# Dictionary attack on unix /etc/shadow passwords using python and hashlib?

Tags: python, unix, crypt, sha512, hashlib

Can it be done this way ? My tests don't seem to work. My plaintext pass is in dictionary.txt, and in password.txt the pass in the format from /etc/shadow file.- I get the pass and hash it using hash.sha512(salt + plaintextpassword).
Then i compare that hash with the password part of 'cat /etc/shadow | grep user'

```
import hashlib
import sys

def checkpass(passwd):
    try:
        semi_c = ':'
        d_sign = '$'
        pwdlist = passwd.split("$")
        salt = '$'+pwdlist[1]+'$'+pwdlist[2]+'$'
        print 'Salt is : ' + salt
        cryptPas = passwd.split(d_sign, 3)[3]
        cryptPass = cryptPas.split(semi_c)[0]
        print cryptPass 
        dictFile = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')

        for word in dictFile.readlines():

                word = word.strip('\n')
                print 'Comparing to pass in list : ' + word + ' to ' + passwd + ' ---- '
                cryptWord = hashlib.sha512(salt + word).hexdigest()
                print 'Reproduced Hash : ' + cryptWord
                if (cryptWord == cryptPass):
                    print '[+] Found Password : ' + word + '\n'
                    return cryptWord
                else:
                    print '[-] Password not found.\n'
                    return cryptWord

    except Exception, e:
        print e
    return  

def main():

    try:
        passfile = open('password.txt')
        passwd = passfile.readline()
        semi_c = ':'
        #print passwd
        if semi_c in passwd:
            user = passwd.split(semi_c)[0]
            print '[*] Cracking Password for : ' + user
            checkpass(passwd)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    return    

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python's hashlib but be aware that crypt() is not only DES, MD5 vor SHA but only based in them. It uses several rounds for example. There should be a Python crypt module.